# Accessing my Mac's Bluetooth via Windows running in VirtualBox

Tags: bluetooth, virtualbox

I am developing a cross platform Bluetooth library for Node.js. I am using a MacBook Pro with built in Bluetooth and now I need to make sure my library works on Windows. I am trying to use VirtualBox to run Windows but that Windows cannot find my system's Bluetooth.

Is there a way to make my Mac's Bluetooth work on a Windows running inside VirtualBox?